# Why my date value the year format missing when save to database???

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

My question is that why my date value display on textbox is with complete year but save into the database change to another format? Why this is happen and what should I do for fixing it?

As when I display in the textbox the format is 11-11-2013 but during insert into the database change to another format which is 11-NOV-13. Why my year format is missing?
I can that I need to do so that save into database will change to 2013.

I will attach my  code for ease of references.
XAML FILE:

```
 <!--DatePickerTextBoxFormat-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

XAML File:

```
<Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="112" Content="Date of Birth " FontSize="20" Height="28" Name="AdddobLbl" />
<DatePicker Canvas.Left="125" Canvas.Top="114" Height="25" Name="AdddobDatePicker" Width="179" FontSize="12" IsTodayHighlighted="False" CalendarOpened="datePicker1_CalendarOpened" SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```

Comment: What is the type of the column? If it is `datetime` (do *not* use varchar!) then it has *no* format.

Comment: Do you store the date as string in the databse? Or as a Date? If you store it as a date, it is just the formatting of the view of the table column. The date is stored correctly, but shown differently depending on if you watch it in your aplication or in the database. If you store it as a string, you have to apply formatting before storing it.

Comment: Although, if you are storing the date as a string - you are storing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you all guys for viewing my question & give some idea for my solution...
I had solved it. As is related with my personal computer setting.
What I do is change the "Short Date" format of my computer from the original "dd/MMM/yy" to "dd/MM/yyyy". That take me some hours of asking Mr.Google until found the solution :)  

http://excelsemipro.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Customize-Regional-Date-Format-1.png

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime data type is actually a number. The formatting is only made for humans. This means that the date most probably is saved correctly.

For instance, in SQL Server the `datetime` data type is stored as a 8 byte value with a range from January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999 and with a accuracy of .001 seconds.

The main reason for this is that numbers are convenient for computers to perform calculations and comparisons on.

The presentation for us humans differ for the use case at hand. You want 11-11-2013 in your application, but I want 2013-11-11 because that is what I am used to. The actual date is the same, it's only the formatting that differs.

Comment: Thank you as your answer give me some idea :)